# Akka supervisor managing supervisors

Tags: akka, akka-supervision

I reckon there might be a broader question of application design using Akka hidden in here but I'll ask how does one set up a supervision tree where a "kernel" or "top" supervisor might supervise children that are other supervisors which supervisor workers?

Comment: Make the top supervisor spawn and link the other supervisors, and have those supervisors spawn and link workers.

Comment: Thanks Viktor, are you aware of an example doing that programatically vs. declaratively?

Comment: You'll have to do it programmatically, check this out for docs: http://doc.akka.io/fault-tolerance-scala

Comment: @Viktor: I converted your suggestions into an answer. Hope that's ok.

Comment: If I have some time I may push out an example to github. I've been using this setup in java quite happily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might start with a declarative supervisor on the top level

```
 val kernel = Supervisor(
     SupervisorConfig(
         OneForOneStrategy(List(classOf[Exception]), 3, 1000),
         Supervise(
             actorOf[Module1],
             Permanent) ::
         Supervise(
             actorOf[Module2],
             Permanent) ::
         Supervise(
             actorOf[Module3],
             Permanent) ::
         Nil
     )
 )
```

where module 1 to 3 represents the next level of your application architecture. Each module itself is a supervisor for all of its child actors and implemented like for example

```
class Module1 extends Actor {
   self.faultHandler = OneForOneStrategy(List(classOf[Throwable]), 5, 5000)

   def receive = {
       case Register(actor) =>
       self.link(actor)
   }
}
```

You might replace the "Register(actor)" message with something more suitable for your application, and you might want to span a further programmatically created supervisor layer but basically that would be the approach to follow.

You'll find further details (as Viktor already commented) in the official akka documentation on [Fault tolerance with Scala](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.2/scala/fault-tolerance.html) or [Fault tolerance with Java](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.2/java/fault-tolerance.html).

Comment: Can I assume that this answer does not hold for Akka 2.x?

Comment: That's right, this is Akka 1.x only. The Supervision-Mechanism was changed completely in 2.x